# Repairing Windows on a different hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, boot

I just got a new computer, and for some reason while updating to Windows 10 Anniversary, the laptop shut off.  Now it will not boot, and BIOS is unavailable unless the hard drive is unplugged.  I removed the hard drive from the laptop and put plugged it into my desktop where the optical drive used to be, and it looks like the update never finished.  Can I repair the Windows installation from my desktop?  If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Make and model of the new computer?

Comment: It is a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 14 (Best Buy version with Geforce 940m).  I just booted my desktop from the laptop hard drive and it worked fine, but when the hard drive is in the laptop it just sits at the Lenovo splash.